# Como validar data levando em conta ano bissexto?

Tags: javascript, validação, data

Como validar data com ano bissexto no JavaScript?

Answer (score 14):

Outro jeito é verificar em que mês cai o dia 29 de fevereiro (29 de fevereiro ou 1 de março?). Se for fevereiro o ano é bissexto:

```
function anoBissexto(ano) {
    return new Date(ano, 1, 29).getMonth() == 1
}
```

Lembrando que os meses vão de 0 a 11 para o objeto Date do JavaScript (o mês 1 é fevereiro).

Comment: Gostei, boa lógica.

Answer (score 4):

Olá, tenta isso aqui:

```
function leapYear(year){
    return ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

validação de data com javascript, verifica também se o ano é bissexto.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>valida data</title>
<script>
function valData(data){//dd/mm/aaaa

day = data.substring(0,2);
month = data.substring(3,5);
year = data.substring(6,10);

if( (month==01) || (month==03) || (month==05) || (month==07) || (month==08) || (month==10) || (month==12) )    {//mes com 31 dias
if( (day < 01) || (day > 31) ){
    alert('invalid date');
}
} else

if( (month==04) || (month==06) || (month==09) || (month==11) ){//mes com 30 dias
if( (day < 01) || (day > 30) ){
    alert('invalid date');
}
} else

if( (month==02) ){//February and leap year
if( (year % 4 == 0) && ( (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0) ) ){
if( (day < 01) || (day > 29) ){
    alert('invalid date');
}
} else {
if( (day < 01) || (day > 28) ){
alert('invalid date');
}
}
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="data" id="data" onBlur="return valData(this.value)" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Acho muito código pra pouco resultado, quando seu código é extenso demais para pouca coisa significa que não foi desenvolvido corretamente. Alguem me disse uma vez `Um código perfeito não é aquele que não se tem mais nada para colocar nele, mas sim o código em que você não tem mais nada para tirar dele`.

Comment: Faltou isso olha: `if( (month >12)){ alert('invalid date'); }` está entrando mês acima de 12.

Answer (score -2):

Aqui está uma função que eu fiz. É simples e funciona de certa forma:

```
function ValidarData() {
    var aAr = typeof (arguments[0]) == "string" ? arguments[0].split("/") : arguments,
        lDay = parseInt(aAr[0]), lMon = parseInt(aAr[1]), lYear = parseInt(aAr[2]),
        BiY = (lYear % 4 == 0 && lYear % 100 != 0) || lYear % 400 == 0,
        MT = [1, BiY ? -1 : -2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1];
    return lMon <= 12 && lMon > 0 && lDay <= MT[lMon - 1] + 30 && lDay > 0;
}

ValidarData(31,12,2016) // True
```

ou

```
ValidarData("29/02/2017") // False
```

Answer (score -4):

```
if ((ano % 4 == 0) && ((ano % 100 != 0) || (ano % 400 == 0))
```

Comment: Stromdh, explique o que o código, que você respondeu, faz.

Comment: Qual a diferença da sua resposta com a do f.fujihara?